# Como usar SUM con codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

estoy tratando de hacer un reporte de de las ventas de mi sistema, la visualización de mi reporte lo estoy haciendo por medio de datatable-export pero esta solo me lista la tabla q cumple las condiciones. Ahora necesito agregar el total de las ventas a mi informe se que debo usar el comando SUM pero la vd a pesar de algunos ejemplos q he visto sigo sin estar con mucha idea

**Este es el controlador, donde listo todas las ventas y de la vista estiro las fechas que uso como parametro**

```
public function index()
{   $fechaInicio = $this->input->post("fechainicio");
    $fechaFin = $this->input->post("fechafin");
    if ($this->input->post("buscar")) //pregunta si se presiono el boton buscar
    {
        $ventas = $this->Ventas_models->getVentasByDate($fechaInicio, $fechaFin);
    }
    else
    {
        $ventas = $this->Ventas_models->getVentas();
    }
    $data = array
    (
        'ventas' => $ventas, // se carga en el array la variable ventas q se obtuvo en el if de arriba 
    );
    $this->load->view("layouts/header");
    $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
    $this->load->view("admin/reportes/Rep_Ventas", $data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");
}
```

**Este el modelo donde recupero las ventas a ser enviadas al controlador**

```
public function getVentasByDate($inicio, $fin)
{
    $this->db->select("v.*,c.nombres_cliente,tc.nombre_tComprobante as tComprobante");
    $this->db->from("ventas v");
    $this->db->join("clientes c","v.cliente_id_ventas = c.id_cliente");
    $this->db->join("tipo_comprobante tc","v.tipo_comprobante_id_ventas = tc.id_tComprobante");
    $this->db->where("v.fecha_ventas >=",$inicio);
    $this->db->where("v.fecha_ventas <=",$fin);
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    if ($resultados->num_rows()>0) 
    {
        return $resultados->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

la columna que quiero sumar el total_ventas osea v.total_ventas Gracias!!

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres sumar? Los valores de una columna de v? En ese caso puedes realizar otra consulta para ello.

Comment: perdon se me paso esa parte, la columna se llama total_ventas, osea seria v.total_ventas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que quieres sumar todos los valores de una columna de la tabla `ventas`, tienes que hacerlo en una consulta separada:

```
$this->db->select_sum('total_ventas', 'total');
$this->db->where('fecha_ventas >=', $inicio);
$this->db->where('fecha_ventas <=', $fin);
$query = $this->db->get('ventas');
$resultado = $query->result();
$total = $resultado[0]->total;
```

Más información: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Error Number:1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`NULL` AND `v`.`fecha_ventas` < `IS` `NULL`' at line 5
SELECT `v`.*, `c`.`nombres_cliente`, `tc`.`nombre_tComprobante` as `tComprobante`, SUM(`v`.`total_ventas`) AS `total_ventas` FROM (`ventas` `v`, `ventas`) JOIN `clientes` `c` ON `v`.`cliente_id_ventas` = `c`.`id_cliente` JOIN `tipo_comprobante` `tc` ON `v`.`tipo_comprobante_id_ventas` = `tc`.`id_tComprobante` WHERE `v`.`fecha_ventas` > `IS` `NULL` AND `v`.`fecha_ventas` < `IS` `NULL`

Comment: me sale ese error quiere decir q esta recibiendo $inicio y $fin como NULL? porq en la consulta q genero en mi pregunta principal recibe bien los valores. o me indica otra cosa ese error??

Comment: Parece que $inicio y $fin son null, sí. Además, el código que te he puesto es una consulta separada, no tienes que añadirle los join, from y select que están arriba

Comment: en la linea $resultado = $resultados->result(); $resultado no debe ser igual a $query->result();? como veras soy bien nuevo con esto. Muchisimas gracias x la ayuda!!

Comment: Yo he usado otra nomenclatura, te recomiendo que pongas mi código en una función diferente y luego ya renombres las variables como quieras. De nada ;)

Comment: si puse en una función diferente, pero la llame desde la misma funcion del controlador 

if ($this->input->post("buscar")) //pregunta si se presiono el boton buscar
{
  $ventas = $this->Ventas_models->getVentasByDate($fechaInicio, $fechaFin);
  $total = $this->Ventas_models->getTotalVentas($fechaInicio, $fechaFin);
}

de esta forma cuando llama solo GetVentasByDate funciona sin problemas pero al llamar a getTotalVentas pasa NULL. ese sera el problema??

Comment: Es imposible debugear sin tener el código, creo que ya te he dado una idea de por dónde seguir y he respondido a tu pregunta principal

Comment: es cierto, muchas Gracias nuevamente amigo!!